# When scraping website using scrapy, How to generate request dynamically?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, request, web-crawler

I am trying to **scrape** data from website using scrapy. But Page is generated using Request which means url + other data(I found that using developer tools of browser).
I copy the request as cURL and translated it to scrapy using [curl to scrapy](https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/) link.  I can get data from these page when I create request manually and then fetch.
So I need to create request manually. My Question is how can I create request dynamically in spider.

```
class PowerGenerationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "power_generation"
    # make request
    url = 'http://my/website'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Authorization": "authorization_string",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Origin": "http://my/website",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "mywebsite"
}
# need to run this for month 01 to 10 or how can i change this programatically
body = '{"month":"01","year":"2020","user_id":"vishvajeet"}'

request = scrapy.Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    dont_filter=True,
    headers=headers,
    body=body,
)

def start_requests(self):
    yield self.request #scrapy.Request(self.request, self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    solar_energy_datalist = data["resultObject"]
    item = PowerGenerationItem()
    for solar_energy_data in solar_energy_datalist:
        date = solar_energy_data['date']
        power_generation = solar_energy_data['power_generation']

        item['date'] = date
        item['power_generation'] = power_generation
        yield item
```

how can i generate request with diffrent parameter inside body of request and pass it to the crawl for next request to crawl.
Note: I found other resource on web which tell how to generate url dynamically. This is not about url, I want to generate request becaues URL is same.

edit 1:
cURL which i converted to scrapy request is below. i might delete authentication related information later.

```
curl 'http://3.6.0.2/inject-solar-angular/inject_solar_server/graph/Graph/cumulative_month_graph' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjkwIiwicm9sZSI6IjQiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1OTU1NjcxMjEsInN0YXR1cyI6MX0.-RFFUc69PxDsAk_zmn3VI8OqUh-mYkYioFyTSBU17_s' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Origin: http://www.injectsolar.com' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: http://www.injectsolar.com/portal/' --data-raw '{"month":"01","year":"2020","user_id":"triose"}'
```

edit: 2

I am trying to fetch jan-20 to june-20 data on daily basis of power generation. for that i need to change the parameter inside body. If inside body directory month=01 it give jan-20 data. If i change it to month=02 it give me feb data. But I want to do this automatically through crawler. As if crawler crawl from one page to other page. It should give me data like that.

Answer (score 0):

A few things in terms of the code provided. I would like you to provide abit more code of an attempt at trying to generate the request with different body parameters dynamically. This is something I don't see in your code yet, so there's only so much I can help. But there's enough in this text here to show you how to transfer ANY information you want from one function to another so you should be able to make an attempt.

As another disclaimer, because I don't have the URL, I can't run this code myself, so again it's hard to unpick if there's problems with it.

### Corrections

1. Just put the scrapy Request within `start_requests` function
2. Refering to variables outside the function requires you to add self.VARIABLE. In this case `self.headers`
3. To input the parameters you need to use the meta argument. So `cb_kwargs = self.body`. The `cb_kwargs` argument is used to transfer any dictionary of information you want from one function to another. Headers is a defined argument in `scrapy.Request`, so it doesn't apply to that. But the body dictionary you created is user created information and the cb_kwargs argument applies to this.
4. You need to define a callback for the response to be processed. Here we define the callback as `self.parse` which is the default callback for the `start_requests` function.
5. Unless the url is different to URL in the `start_urls`. Refer to the URL argument in the scrapy.Request as `self.start_urls[0]`. In this case you've defined the variable url, so in your `scrapy.Request` you need to refer to it as `self.url`

### Code Example

```
   class PowerGenerationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "power_generation"
        # make request
        url = 'http://my/website'

        headers = {
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
           "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "Authorization": "authorization_string",
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Origin": "http://my/website",
           "DNT": "1",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Referer": "mywebsite"
              }
   # need to run this for month 01 to 10 or how can i change this programatically
        body = {"month":"01","year":"2020","user_id":"vishvajeet"}



        def start_requests(self):
             yield scrapy.Request(
                              url=self.url,
                              method='POST',
                              dont_filter=True,
                              headers=self.headers,
                              cb_kwargs=self.body,
                              callback=self.parse
                             )

        def parse(self, response):
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            solar_energy_datalist = data["resultObject"]
            item = PowerGenerationItem()
            for solar_energy_data in solar_energy_datalist:
                date = solar_energy_data['date']
                power_generation = solar_energy_data['power_generation']

                item['date'] = date
                item['power_generation'] = power_generation
                yield item
```

### Additional Information

1. Remember that the `start_requests` function is used to generate requests for the start_urls.
2. The `self.VARIABLE` comes from knowing about classes. Understanding what this means is essential to following along this example. The beauty of `self.VARIABLE` means that if you define a variable in a class that is NOT within a funtion in the class, it can be used in ANY function within the class but you have to remember to refer to as `self.VARIABLE` in each function. This type of variable is called a class variable.
3. Consider ItemLoaders for extracting data if you need to modify the responses scrapy gives you or want to apply a small function to the extracted data to clean it up. ItemLoaders gives you a lot more freedom to change the outputs of the scrapy responses.

### Resources for additional learning

1. For more information about class variables please see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)
2. Read the scrapy docs for `scrapy.Request` [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) if you read carefully it will explain about cb_kwargs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments) but also you should have a better understanding of the arguments you can use.

Comment: I created before request method inside start_request but i got an error so for fixing that i created it separately and added it into request. now I made changes in start_request again i got error. `/scrapy/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._cb_kwargs = dict(cb_kwargs) if cb_kwargs else None
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
`

Comment: also i didn't got how this will solve my problem of sending different parameter to body ? I am expecting it has something to do in parse_method.  which we normally do for next url.

Comment: For the first error, can you please update your code in your question or use pastebin to upload the code you are explicility using in scrapy as I'm unable to unpack that. The other thing really is that I don't know what URL you're trying to get information from so I can't run the code myself, this limits me in how much help I can give you. I think some additional code from you would help in terms of an attempt at dynamic body content. But as some advice essentially any dictionary of any data you want to pass can be used in the cb_kwargs argument of any scrapy.Request.

Comment: Actually, in your code you've specified body as a string. It should be a dictionary for cb_kwargs argument, it will only handle a dictionary which may be why you're getting that error. I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: I just changed start_request method from mycode to your code. and got above error. I added cURL you can use it with scrapy by converting the link i mention above and try to replicate

Comment: So having now had a chance to play about with the code. Firstly the injectsolar page is behind a login so you'll need to login and post the cookie/sessionid to be able to successful make requests to the API you're trying. Making the request with your headers and params is not getting me access either with your code OR mine. With mine I get a service 500 error and your code I get {'status': False, 'resultObject': [], 'message': 'User Not Found'} as output. There was a slight error in my code, I put a ] in the url=self.url, bit I've corrected that. In your code you hadnt provided any imports.

Comment: In terms of your actual problem, you still haven't provided any attempt really...I'm sure with a bit of effort on your part you couldve come up with how to generate either a dictionary value/string that changes. For your code using f-strings in your code to dynamically create the correct string is the approach.

Comment: I updated code. I hop It will provide all you needed. I appreciate your help. but I definetly try what I can, including finding answer on internet for resonable amount ot time. I am not aware of f-string as of now. I am looking into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218509/discussion-between-vishvajeet-ramanuj-and-aarons).